# Where should I reimplement QAbstractItemModel::supportedDragActions()?

Tags: c++, qt, overriding

I am migrating a project from Qt 4.x to 5, and the next function is obsolete:

```
model->setSupportedDragActions(Qt::MoveAction);
```

I have researched and apparently I have to reimplement the function / override a virtual one called supportedDragActions() [This guy](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/24063) had the same problem with the function and solved it.
My newbie question is, where should I reimplement such function? in the qabstractitemmodel.h/cpp? or somewhere in another class?

Forgive my ignorance.

Thankyou.

EDIT:
I implemented the function in my cpp, right above the function that calls setSupportedDragActions(), like this:

```
mapmodulelist.cpp:
void QAbstractItemModel::setSupportedDragActions(Qt::DropActions actions){
    Q_D(QAbstractItemModel);
    d->supportedDragActions = actions;
}

void MapModuleList::setupModel() {
    if (mapLayersModel == NULL) {
        mapLayersModel = new QStandardItemModel(0);
        mapLayersModel ->setSupportedDragActions(Qt::MoveAction);
    }
}
```

mapLayersModel is a member of this class, this is its declaration:

```
static QStandardItemModel* mapLayersModel;
```

I also had to add a header to qabstractitemmodel.h:

```
void setSupportedDragActions(Qt::DropActions actions);
```

I get the next errors:

```
invalid use of incomplete type 'class QAbstractItemModelPrivate'
     d->supportedDragActions = actions;
      ^
```

and

```
forward declaration of 'class QAbstractItemModelPrivate'
 class QAbstractItemModelPrivate;
       ^
```

I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement (rather override) this virtual function in **your model** subclass, i.e. in the same class where you implemented the obsolete `setSupportedDragActions()` function. This only necessary if you need drag and drop functionality for your views.

Comment: I tried doing this and you are probably right but I must have implemented the function in the wrong place.

Comment: Please explain, why do you need to implement this function? You use `QStandardItemModel` directly, as I can see, and the way you are trying to change something is not supported by language (C++).

Comment: Because in the code I am migrating it uses it, so I need to keep the functionality the same but its deprecated. I don't understand what you mean by that I use QStandardItemModel. I added the function to QAbstractItemModel because QStandardItemModel extends this one, so I figured out I could implement it there. I didnt find a CPP so I implemented the function in my CPP.

Comment: I managed to solve it, it was what you said, and  apparently there is a function that does the same as setSupportedDragActions but its called doSetSupportedDragActions but its private, so I just made a function that called that one and voila. Thankyou very much.